# is there any way to enable xbox cursor for uwp games?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp

My game, built with Unity for UWP, how can i enable this pointer for my game?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mouse support is only 'enabled' for specific applications. It's not available to general UWP on Xbox applications.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Chuck Walbourn's answer, there is something else I want to add.

If you mean that you want to have hardware mouse support, then @Chuck Walbourn is right.

If you want to emulate a pointer with non-pointer input devices such as an Xbox gamepad or remote control, you could try to set the [Application.RequiresPointerMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requirespointermode?view=winrt-22621).

You could call it like this:

```
 public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        this.RequiresPointerMode = ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
    }
```

Comment: when we create unity UWP.
the code is c++ not c#,

Comment: @Babakmoghaddasi I'm not familiar with C++, but if it's a UWP app, the property should be the same. What you need to do is to set the **Application.RequiresPointerMode Property**.

Comment: its a game not application, your code is for app

Comment: @Babakmoghaddasi Ok, so you need to refer to Chuck Walbourn's answer. The mouse support is not supported for Xbox.